# Using Icons in Kendo Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid 1.0.7.  has anyone used an icon (material or kendo icon) in the grid?

I've tried passing the information in the array.  So far I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer my own question.  I must have looked at the API 100 times and missed this.  I need more coffee.  Plus stop writing code on a holiday weekend.... Hope this helps someone if they are looking for it too in the future....

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar k-icon-32"></span>
</ng-template>
```

Please notes, I was just doing VERY dummy data there to get it working.